# File extension type to be downloaded

Tags: java, file, download, httpclient, file-extension

How can I determine the file extension of a file I want to download? I am using the code below to download the file.

```
URL url = new URL("http://server.com/file.format");
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), null));

InputStream in = client.execute(get).getEntity().getContent();

//... read input stream and save to file
```

I have had a look on other related threads, but I couldn't find a solution to me problem.

Comment: It depends on what exactly are you trying to achieve. You can get it from URL, guess it from `Content-Type` header or guess it from the contents of the file.

Comment: In some case, file extension is not exist in URL! Guess is not return File Extension, it only returns MIME-Type!

Answer (score 2):

On the internet, and in the unix world, there is no such thing as a mandatory file extension. That is a typical windows-world way of thinking.

In HTTP, the closest thing to a "file extension" is the mime type. It is an actual content type description such as `text/html` or `image/gif`. But HTTP does not supply a **file extension**. You'd have to map the mime types to the file extensions yourself!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your extension in your example is "format". In other words it is in the string used to make the URL used to request the file. To get the extension from a passed in file string used to make a URL use:

```
str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.')+1)
```

[Edited]

Comment: Of-course, but i want to get extension file type with using for example MIME-Type ( Content-Type of file ).

Comment: And please note that with this method, we should use `str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);`